# Add-in MSForms.ListBox

Tags: vba, excel, listbox, add-in

I wrote a function to populate a listbox object :

```
Sub populate_listBox(ByRef wsSheet As Worksheet, ByRef colonne As String, ByRef myListBox As MSForms.ListBox)

Dim rnData As Range
Dim vaData As Variant               'the list, stored in a variant
Dim ncData As New VBA.Collection    'the list, stored in a collection
Dim lnCount As Long                 'the count used in the On Error Resume Next loop.
Dim vaItem As Variant               'a variant representing the type of items in ncData

'Using Sheet2,retrieve the range of the list in Column A.
With wsSheet
    Set rnData = .Range(.Range(colonne & "2"), .Range(colonne & "2").End(xlDown))
    'Set rnData = .Range("D:D")
    rnData.Sort Key1:=.Range(colonne & "2"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
End With

'Place the list values into vaData.
vaData = rnData.Value
'Place the list values from vaData into the VBA.Collection.
On Error Resume Next
For lnCount = 1 To UBound(vaData)
    ncData.Add vaData(lnCount, 1), CStr(vaData(lnCount, 1))
Next lnCount
On Error GoTo 0

'Clear the List box (in case you ran the macro before),
'and then add each unique variant item from ncData to the combo box.

With myListBox
    .Clear
    For Each vaItem In ncData
        .AddItem vaItem
    Next vaItem
End With

End Sub
```

This function works very well when it is defined in the current project :

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim wsSheet As Worksheet

Set wsSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("data")
wsSheet.AutoFilterMode = False

Call populate_listBox(wsSheet, "F", UserFormCoutMoyen.ListBoxReparateurs)

End Sub
```

But I am currently using an Add-in project called src_vba.xlam.
I added the *populate_listBox* function to this Add-in but it raises an error when I called it :

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
'The Excel workbook and worksheets that contain the data, as well as the range placed on that data

Dim wsSheet As Worksheet

Set wsSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("data")
wsSheet.AutoFilterMode = False

Call src.populate_listBox(wsSheet, "F", UserFormCoutMoyen.ListBoxReparateurs)

End Sub
```

The message error is : *"type defined by user is not defined"* and the application stopped on that line :

```
Sub populate_listBox(ByRef wsSheet As Worksheet, ByRef colonne As String, ByRef myListBox As MSForms.ListBox)
```

I think that the problem is about the definition of the listbox when I use an Add-in function as it works well before using Add-in.

Could you please tell me what do I have to modify?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Probably your old project had a reference that imported MSForms.ListBox. Check the references each are using and make sure they match. Menu is at `Tools > References...` in the VBE

Comment: Thank you very much!   I add the *Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library* reference to my Add-in project and It works well.